# Show $f$ is discontinuous at every odd integer if $f(x)=x, -1< x< 1, $ $f(x+2)=x,\forall x\notin (-1,1)$

Tags: functions, continuity, piecewise-continuity

Let $f$ be a real function defined as follows:

$f(x)=x, -1< x< 1, $

$f(x+2)=x,\forall x\notin (-1,1)$

Show that $f$ is discontinuous at every odd integer.

My work:

The function is continuous in $(-1,1)$. I have proved discontinuity at $x=-1, 1$.

Now, for any integer $x=2n+1, n\in I$, the function is coming out to be continuous as per the following reasoning.

At $x=2n+1$

LHL = $\lim \limits_{h \to 0}f(2n+1-h)=\lim \limits_{h \to 0}f[(2n+1-h-2)+2]=\lim \limits_{h \to 0}2n+1-h-2=2n-1$

RHL = $\lim \limits_{h \to 0}f(2n+1+h)=\lim \limits_{h \to 0}f[(2n+1+h-2)+2]=\lim \limits_{h \to 0}2n+1+h-2=2n-1$

Also, $f(2n+1)=f[(2n+1-2)+2]=2n-1$

So, according to me, LHL=RHL=$f(2n+1)$.

How is it discontinuous at odd integers?

Comment: I'm assuming that $\mathfrak{R}$ denotes the real numbers. If I'm not mistaken, this function is not even well defined on the real numbers. For example, $f(0) = 0$ by the first rule, but $f(0) = -2$ by the second.

Comment: @Aurel: Yes it denotes the real numbers. I have copied the question as it as given in the worksheet. I have taken it to mean $f(x)=f(x+2) \forall x \in \Re - (-1,1)$

Comment: I will edit the question.

Comment: With that definition, it is discontinuous only for $x=1,-1$.

Comment: Think about the case $f(3)$. It cannot be defined using the first definition since $3>1$, and neither using the second definition since $f(3)=f(1+2)$ and $1\in [-1, 1]$

Comment: @user3141592: You are right. There could be a misprint in the worksheet. How about if I lose the $\le$ and replace it by <. I will make the necessary edit.

Comment: With  new definition, let's analyse $f(5)$. $f(5-ε)=3-ε$; $f(5+ε)=3+ε$ and $f(5)=3$ so that it is continuous in $x=5$. This is just a counterexample to your question, which could be generalised for every odd integer greater than 3.

Comment: @user3141592: Yes, I have already shown that in my work (included in the question itself).

Comment: There is a problem with the definition. Lets analyse then $f(0,8)$. By the first definition, $f(0,8)=0,8$. By the second definition, $f(0,8)=f(-1,2+2)=-1,2$ since $-1,2<-1$, isn't it?

Comment: @user3141592: I don't understand. Is it right to change $f(x)$ to $f(x,y)$? Also by first definition $f(0,8)\ne(0,8)$ as $8\notin (-1,1)$

Comment: Sorry, by $0,8$ I wanted to mean $0.8=\frac{8}{10}$ (notation is different in my country)

Comment: You are right. The function does not seem to be correctly defined. I will take this question off. Thank you for your time!

Comment: In spite of that, I will post it as a solution in case there is more people interested on it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a problem with the definition of $f(x)$.

Lets analyse it at $x=0.8$ (this would work for any $|x|<1$):

- By the first definition, $f(0.8)=0.8$.
- By the second definition, $f(0.8)=f(-1.2+2)=-1.2$ since $-1.2<-1$

Then, as for one value of $x$ we have two different values of $f(x)$, either this is not a function or it is not well defined.

(However, for odd integers greater than $3$, it should be continuous since for those sufficiently large values $f(x)=x-2$)